# What is wrong with my mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am sorry if I sound noob but I need some help here. I cant figure out with this query:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE read = 1 AND userid='{$uId}' AND
orderid='{$oId}'; ";
```

When I do a `var_dump` on the query result i get `bool(false)` but when I do the same without the `read = 1` part it returns results correctly so I guess the problem is with the `read = 1` part. Please help, the `read` field type is `tinyint(1)`.

Comment: Are you sure there are rows in the database where read is 1?

Comment: Backtick `read`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html It is a reserved term.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently read is a reserves mysql key word.

Comment: [Output your MySQL errors in the event of a failure, and your problems will be a lot clearer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/300836).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use back-ticks in your query because you used reserved keyword `read`:-**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `msgs` WHERE `read` = 1 AND `userid`='{$uId}' AND `orderid`='{$oId}'";
```

Note:- `read` is reserved keyword here, i added around others because its not easy to remember all reserved keywords so using back-ticks around column name is better approach.

Link for depth knowledge given by @chris85 :- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html